# In Angular, how do I set a class's variable to be the result of a function?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'd like to be able to get a live update of the total of an array of another class.

The Detachment class has a property `CP` which i'd like the Army class to be able to get the sum of from all its Detachments, and make that accessible to anything which creates its own Army.

```
export class Army {
    cost: number;
    CP: number;
    name: string;

    Detachments: Detachment[];

    constructor() {
        this.cost = 0;
        this.name = "";
        this.Detachments = [];

        this.CP = this.getArmyCP();
    }

    getArmyCP() {
        let total = 0;
        for(let i=0; i<this.Detachments.length; i++) {
            total += this.Detachments[i].CP;
        }
        return total;
    }

}
```

I can see the value by directly accessing `Army.getArmyCP()` but is it possible to set Army.CP to access the function by reference?

I've been able to do this in AngularJS, but I'm fairly new to Angular, and TypeScript, so I'm not sure how to emulate this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could solve this with a [getter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors) like this:

```
get CP(): number { return this.getArmyCP(); }
```

So from the outside you can just use it like a normal variable and it will actually call the getter:

```
let myArmyCP = army.CP;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. that was exactly what I'm looking for.
Do I still need to declare `CP: number` at the start of the class, then the getter afterwards, or will the getter alone alow access to the variable?

Comment: You don't need the variable anymore. The getter accesses the method `getArmyCP()` and returns that value as if it was a variable.